# How to Audio Classification in Android give input Audio file?

Tags: android, tensorflow, kotlin, audio, classification

**I Classify a audio file in android use live recording. But I want to classification get a Audio file from android internal or external storage. How do this work? Please help me.**

My mainActivity code is given below, that are->
**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.mysoundclassification

import android.Manifest
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import org.tensorflow.lite.task.audio.classifier.AudioClassifier
import java.util.*
import kotlin.concurrent.scheduleAtFixedRate


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var probabilityThreshold: Float = 0.3f

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val showResult = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.output)

        //Permission For Record
        val REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO = 1337
        requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO), REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO)

        //Load TFLite model
        val audioClassifier = AudioClassifier.createFromFile(this, "my_birds_model.tflite")

        //Real Time Audio Record
        val audioRecord = audioClassifier.createAudioRecord()
        audioRecord.startRecording()

        //Use Thread
        Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(1, 1000) {
            //Classify Sound
            val  tensorAudio= audioClassifier.createInputTensorAudio()
            tensorAudio.load(audioRecord)/** Here,Pass live Record audio data.But,
            ** I want pass here my audio file.
            ** How do this work??
            ** Please help me.
            */
            //Result
            val output = audioClassifier.classify(tensorAudio)

            //*** Start Specifying output....
            //  Check if it's a bird sound.
            var filteredModelOutput = output[0].categories.filter {
                it.label.contains("Bird") && it.score > probabilityThreshold
            }
            //  given there's a bird sound, which one is it?
            if (filteredModelOutput.isNotEmpty()) {
                Log.i("Yamnet", "bird sound detected!")
                filteredModelOutput = output[1].categories.filter {
                    it.score > probabilityThreshold
                }
            }
            val outputStr = filteredModelOutput.sortedBy { -it.score }
                .joinToString(separator = "\n") { "${it.label} -> ${it.score} " }
            if (outputStr.isNotEmpty())
                runOnUiThread {
                    showResult.text = outputStr
                }
            Log.i("output", ""+output[0])
            //*** End Specifying output
        }//End thread

    }//End onCreate method

}//End MainActivity
```

Now the next code is xml file that are->
**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_width="299dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="5"
        android:text="Play your audio!"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.424" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Recording"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/output"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.194" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Need for permission for this work is audio record->
**permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Thanks..please Help, This problem solve is very important for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [`tensorAudio.load(audioRecord: AudioRecord)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/java/org/tensorflow/lite/support/audio/TensorAudio#load(AudioRecord)), you can similarly use [`tensorAudio.load(data: FloatArray)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/java/org/tensorflow/lite/support/audio/TensorAudio#load(float%5B%5D)). You would load the data from internal/external storage into the `data` variable by reading a file as you would normally in Android.

Keep in mind that, in such a case, your recorded files should be encoded using [`ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat#ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT), so you might need to adjust your input data to fit this format. In case you are obtaining the data via MediaRecorder or AudioRecord you should be able to specify the output file format as `ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT` when you initialize the object. In case you are not, maybe you could browse for sound processing libraries for your specific use case, as I'm afraid I haven't found any options to help you.

Please consider writing your concrete steps in a separate answer if you manage to  solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use google's audio task lib: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/audio_classifier

```
// Initialization
AudioClassifierOptions options =
    AudioClassifierOptions.builder()
        .setBaseOptions(BaseOptions.builder().useGpu().build())
        .setMaxResults(1)
        .build();
AudioClassifier classifier =
    AudioClassifier.createFromFileAndOptions(context, modelFile, options);

// Start recording
AudioRecord record = classifier.createAudioRecord();
record.startRecording();

// Load latest audio samples
TensorAudio audioTensor = classifier.createInputTensorAudio();
audioTensor.load(record);

// Run inference
List<Classifications> results = audioClassifier.classify(audioTensor);
```

Comment: `audioClassifier.classify` should be changed to `classifier.classify`

Comment: How to pass model metadata like input output shapes? Any way with AudioClassifierOptions ?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan, audio task is for realtime AudioRecord input, you can implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.8.0' for file input. And th input is fixed like this doc says: # Input: 0.975 seconds of silence as mono 16 kHz waveform samples. (https://www.kaggle.com/models/google/yamnet/frameworks/tfLite)

Comment: I am getting error. Could you please help in this regards, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77578234/1084174